# How can I enable session in Threaded .Net Webservice?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, session

I have a .Net Webservice with 2 following methods:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void A()
{
   HttpSessionState session = Session;

   Thread thread = new Thread(B);
   thread.Start();
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void B()
{
   HttpSessionState session = Session;
}
```

**scenario 1)** When I call **B** method directly, session is not null

**scenario 2)** but when I call **A**, in **B** both session and HttpContext.Current are null.

Why? How can I enable session in **B** in second scenario? How can I access the session in A? Should I pass its session to B? If yes how?

Method B should not have session as parameter.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have to use a global field:

```
/// <summary>
/// Holds the current session for using in threads.
/// </summary>
private HttpSessionState CurrentSession;

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void A()
{
   CurrentSession = Session;

   Thread thread = new Thread(B);
   thread.Start();
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void B()
{
  //for times that method is not called as a thread
  CurrentSession = CurrentSession == null ? Session : CurrentSession;

   HttpSessionState session = CurrentSession;
}
```

Comment: And when the A() is called twice (and the B() is called twice), the both B() calling has same session. This is VERY VERY WRONG.

Comment: Please explain more. What is problem with Twice B() call.

Comment: If it is called by same client always it has same session.

Comment: But you have no guarancee, the call will be made always by the same client. And if so - it's only coincidence, but the concept at all is wrong.

Comment: For each client (Session) `CurrentSession` is different. Study Session and Application life Cycle.

Comment: I know Application life Cycle. But if you are using multithreading, you must go futher and follow the rules of multithreading programming (regardless you are using ASP.NET or Console application).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're starting B in a new Thread.

See http://forums.asp.net/t/1276840.aspx
or
http://forums.asp.net/t/1630651.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void A()
{
   HttpSessionState session = Session;

   Action action = () => B_Core(session);
   Thread thread = new Thread(action);
   thread.Start();
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void B()
{
   HttpSessionState session = Session;
   B_Core(session);
}
private void B_Core(HttpSessionState session)
{
    // todo
}
```